# Access to 'changed' information of observable array in custom binding :update

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

I'm aware that you can retrieve the 'changed' information from the argument passed back to you when you subscribe directly to an observable array.

I'm writing a custom binding based on an observable array and would like to see the same change information in the :update callback.

I didn't seem available.  Is there a way to get it?

I guess I could subscribe to the observable array in the :init and define my own update callback, but that didn't feel right.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding Updates are triggered after of the observable and is equivalent to subscribing to the change event, so what you want isn't natively possible in the current knockout framework

In order to get access to the value BEFORE the change you will need to subscribe to the observable's beforeChange event.

You can still do the work in the update handler with a bit of slight-of-hand.

```
init: function( element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext ) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();

    // Attach a new observable to the existing observable for use in the use in the update handler
    observable.beforeValue = ko.observable();
    var subscription = observable.subscribe(function(oldValue) {
      observable.beforeValue(oldValue);
    }, null, 'beforeChange');

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(function() { subscription.dispose(); } );
},
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext ) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();

    var beforeValue = observable.beforeValue();
    var currentValue = observable();

    // Do update stuff here
}
```